# grunt not updating index.html with new bower install of bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yeoman-generator-angular

Have a angular scaffolding using yeoman

```
yo angular-fullstack
```

Installed bootstrap

```
bower install bootstrap --save
```

Typically the index.html file updates with a

```
<script src="file.js">
```

but in this case it does not.  Any thoughts on why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After installing your Bower package launch grunt wiredep to Inject Bower packages into your index.html